# xamarin ios. No valid iOS code signing keys

Tags: ios, xamarin

*No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com.*

This error shown when create **ipa** file. I make configuration = Ad-Hoc
and platform iPhone

Comment: have you requested a codesigning cert from apple?

Comment: @jason Yes I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this error shown when create ipa file

Your app needs to be signed with your private key whether you're building for ad hoc or App Store distribution. Follow the error message's advice and request a code signing certificate.

Comment: I already did it and I've extracted a version before
but now when build get this error @Caleb

Answer (score 0):

> No valid iOS code signing keys found in keychain. You need to request
>   a codesigning certificate from https://developer.apple.com.

Please check if your iOS certificate has expired. If so, create a new one.

Reference:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/73093/no-valid-ios-code-signing-keys-found-in-keychain-you-need-to-request-a-codesigning-certificate